# Hive throws: WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0x8)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed hadoop and hive following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm) tutorial. The tutorial is outdated so I used the current versions. When I start hive I get the following error:

> hive 
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory] Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal character entity:
>   expansion character (code 0x8  at [row,col,system-id]:
>   [3210,96,"file:.../software/apache-hive-3.1.0-bin/conf/hive-site.xml"]
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3003)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2931)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2806)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1460)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getVar(HiveConf.java:4990)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.getVar(HiveConf.java:5063)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5150)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.(HiveConf.java:5093)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:81)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)

I had a look at the specified file and found this entry:

```
<description>
  Ensures commands with OVERWRITE (such as INSERT OVERWRITE) acquire Exclusive locks for&#8;transactional tables.  This ensures that inserts (w/o overwrite) running concurrently
  are not hidden by the INSERT OVERWRITE.
</description>
```

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04, hive 3.1.0, derby 10.8.1.2, hadoop 3.1.1, Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
. I added some lines to the file for configuration as outlined in the tutorial, though I did not touch this lines at all. Do I have to download a different version of hive?

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc? Also, Can you try deleting the file metastore_db/dbex.lck from the current directory (SPARK_HOME)?

Comment: Yes JAVA_HOME is configured. There is no metastore_db directory in my current directory.

Comment: SPARK_HOME? and what version of JAVA you using?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_181"

Comment: Can you use JAVA not the open JDK and problem is in this line &#8

Comment: Delete this &#8; (including semi-colon) and save the file.

Comment: Why is it in the file in the first place?

Comment: Try that and probably at the time of editing it you might have saved in some different encoding.

Comment: It worked. I run into different errors `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
` which I fixed to. I wonder what caused the error though.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have something like this in `hive-site.xml`

> Ensures commands with OVERWRITE (such as INSERT OVERWRITE) acquire Exclusive locks fortransactional tables.  This ensures that inserts (w/o overwrite) running concurrently
>     are not hidden by the INSERT OVERWRITE.

It is throwing that error, as there is a special character () between the words ***for*** and ***transactional***. Either delete that character or copy and paste (replace) which is in between `<description>` and `</description>`.

```
<description>
     Ensures commands with OVERWRITE (such as INSERT OVERWRITE) acquire Exclusive locks for 
     transactional tables. This ensures that inserts (w/o overwrite) running concurrently
     are not hidden by the INSERT OVERWRITE.
</description>
```

Comment: When viewed using Sublime text editor, that character should look like this: `for&#8;transactional`. Make sure that you change it to `for transactional`.

Comment: This character is included in hive-default.xml.template when you download hive...

Answer (score 4):

Remove Special charters at 3210,96 line and column and just re-run the hive. 
[3210,96,"file:/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-site.xml"]